# Getting code 403 and 'insufficient credential type' error while trying to delete Google Calendar events through API v3

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I'm trying to delete events from Google Calendar. However the owner of events is removed, therefore I have to delete the events through Calendar API v3. But I got code 403 and the error: "This error may be due to using an insufficient credential type. Try using OAuth 2.0."

I asked the one who have workspace admin account to try to delete the event but she stil got code 403 and the same error.